# Архитектура Single Page Application

Tags: mvc, frontend, spa

Никак не могу понять архитектуру SPA сайта.
Объясните как можно проще что за что отвечает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основным признаком одностраничного приложения (Single Page Application / SPA) является то, что для всех веб-страниц используется единственный HTML-документ, а взаимодействие с пользователем осуществляется через все, что можно подгрузить - HTML, CSS, JavaScript и т.п.

Одна из главных задач таких приложений - обеспечить пользователю интерфейс и опыт взаимодействия, аналогичный  десктопным программам.

Основными элементами, использующимися при построении SPA, являются:

- Фреймворки для JavaScript, в частности MVC и MVVM-фреймворки
- Роутинг: навигация между представлениями (view) производится во фронтенде
- Шаблонизатор HTML5 API для бэкэнда, например, в стиле REST
- Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Как следует из названия - "приложение одной страницы".
Другими словами SPA – это web-приложение, размещенное на одной web-странице

Comment: не ясно что делает сервер, а что делает клиент.p.s минуc не я поставил :)

Comment: @monvl эммм перефразируйте вопрос... я затрудняюсь ответить  на вопрос "что делает сервер, а что делает клиент". Сервер делает все тоже самое, что делал и в не SPA также как и фронтенд. вот только фронтенд уменьшен до одной страницы. Что конкретно Вас интересует в работе сервера или фронта? Для примера можете посмотреть почту гугла!